# Split row into columns in R

Tags: r, string, split, row

I have a data-frame with 9 columns. The ninth column has data mixed together, I would like to split this:

```
gene_id ENSG00000243485.3; gene_type lincRNA; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name RP11-34P13.3; level 2; tag ncRNA_host; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000959.2;
```

So that it looks like this:

```
 gene_id            gene_type gene_status  gene_name     havana_gene 
 ENSG00000243485.3  lincRNA   KNOWN        RP11-34P13.3  OTTHUMG00000000959.2
```

So I would like to split the row by the semi-colon delimiter.

Can someone please suggest the best way to do this? I have tried

```
strsplit(lncRNA.gene$V9,';',fixed=TRUE)
```

but I got the error of

```
  Error in strsplit(lncRNA.gene$V9, ";", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument
```

Comment: Try `strsplit(as.character(lncRNA.gene$V9),';',fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: The error you get is because your column is probably a `factor`. Try splitting on `as.character(lncRNA.gene$V9)` instead to get rid of the error.

Comment: How can I save it so its in the original df after the split?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `data.frame` that looks something like:

```
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1, V9 = "gene_id ENSG00000243485.3; gene_type lincRNA; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name RP11-34P13.3; level 2; tag ncRNA_host; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000959.2;")
```

(except with more than just two columns) you can try something like:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(magrittr)

mydf %>%
  cSplit("V9", ";", "long") %>%          # First, split at the semicolon
  cSplit("V9", " ") %>%                  # Then, split on a space
  dcast(... ~ V9_1, value.var = "V9_2")  # Finally, make the data wide

#    id           gene_id    gene_name gene_status gene_type          havana_gene level        tag
# 1:  1 ENSG00000243485.3 RP11-34P13.3       KNOWN   lincRNA OTTHUMG00000000959.2     2 ncRNA_host
```

However, if there are duplicates in "V9_1" when you do the second split, this will default to tabulation. In that case, read the help file for `?getanID`, which would help in such situations.

Comment: That worked, thanks, but it only leaves column 9. How can I make it so that its part of the original data-frame?

Comment: @espop23, it should have all of the other columns there (just like I still had the "id" column in my result). If not, just `cbind` the result back with your original data.

Comment: Its not working out properly.. the data comes out like:     'V1      V2   V3     V4     V5 V6 V7 V8                                                                                            V9
1 chr1 ENSEMBL gene  17369  17436  .  -  .  gene_id ENSG00000278267.1; gene_type miRNA; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name MIR6859-1; level 3;
2 chr1 ENSEMBL gene  30366  30503  .  +  .  gene_id ENSG00000274890.1; gene_type miRNA; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name MIR1302-2; level 3;'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without the use of external libraries

```
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1, V9 = "gene_id ENSG00000243485.3; gene_type lincRNA; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name RP11-34P13.3; level 2; tag ncRNA_host; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000959.2;")
mydf <- rbind(mydf,mydf)     # rbind the mydf with mydf for 2 observations

#Split the V9 by semicolon
splitBySemiColon <- strsplit(as.character(mydf$V9),';')      

# Removal of whitespaces at start and end of the string
splitBySemiColon <- lapply(splitBySemiColon , function(x) trimws(x,which = c('both')))    

#Split by space to fetch the values and column names separately 
splitBySpace <- lapply(splitBySemiColon ,function(x) strsplit(x,' '))    

# Extraction of column names
colnames <- sapply(splitBySpace[[1]], `[[`, 1)

# data.frame of the values
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(splitBySpace, function(x) sapply(x, `[[`, 2)))
colnames(df) <- colnames

# Column bind with the other columns
df <- cbind(mydf[,1:2],df)
```

Note: The V9 should have the same number of fields

Answer (score 0):

I think it's risky to use strsplit because the file format spec doesn't require gene_type, gene_status, etc to be in the same order for all rows. You are far better off going with a [dedicated library](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/rtracklayer.html) that is designed to parse this kind of data

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("rtracklayer")
library(rtracklayer)
x<-import("data.gff")
x$gene_name #RP11-34P13.3
```